# AoCG2021 Day 11: Garbageful streams

Tags: code-golf, string, parsing, balanced-string

Part of [**Advent of Code Golf 2021**](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24068/78410) event. See the linked meta post for details.

Related to [AoC2017 Day 9](https://adventofcode.com/2017/day/9).

*[Weekends are Bubbler's days off from posting these lol](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59839491#59839491)*

---

A large stream blocks your path. According to the locals, it's not safe to cross the stream at the moment because it's full of garbage. You look down at the stream; rather than water, you discover that it's a stream of characters.

You sit for a while and record part of the stream (the input). The characters represent groups - sequences that begin with `{` and end with `}`. Within a group, there are zero or more other things, separated by commas: either another group or garbage. Since groups can contain other groups, a `}` only closes the most-recently-opened unclosed group - that is, they are nestable. The input represents a single group which itself may or may not contain smaller ones.

Sometimes, instead of a group, you will find garbage. Garbage begins with `<` and ends with `>`. Between those angle brackets, almost any character can appear, including `{` and `}`. Within garbage, `<` has no special meaning.

In a futile attempt to clean up the garbage, some program has canceled some of the characters within it using `!`: inside garbage, any character that comes after `!` should be ignored, including `<`, `>`, and even another `!`.

You don't see any characters that deviate from these rules. Outside garbage, you only find well-formed groups, and garbage always terminates according to the rules above.

The following are some example streams with the number of groups they contain:

- `{}`, 1 group.
- `{{{}}}`, 3 groups.
- `{{},{}}`, also 3 groups.
- `{{{},{},{{}}}}`, 6 groups.
- `{<{},{},{{}}>}`, 1 group (which itself contains garbage).
- `{<a>,<a>,<a>,<a>}`, 1 group (containing four pieces of garbage).
- `{{<a>},{<a>},{<a>},{<a>}}`, 5 groups.
- `{{<!>},{<!>},{<!>},{<a>}}`, 2 groups (since all `>`s except the last one are cancelled, creating one large garbage).
- `{{<!!>,{<abc>},<!!!>>,{{<{!>}>},<yes<<<no>}},<>}`, 5 groups.

**Input:** A self-contained, well-formed group as a string.

**Output:** The total number of groups it contains, including itself.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: So `!` only cancels the single character after it? I think that it should be made clear that it's only the one character after `!` that is ignored

Comment: Suggested test case: `{{<>,<!!>}}, 2 groups`. My initial approach worked for all existing test cases, but not for this one (because I removed `!>` before `!!`, and therefore also incorrectly removed `!}`).

Answer (score 15):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 12 bytes

```
!.

<.*?>

}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY1BCoBACEX33mIWQYR0ArFl12iKFm0mqDYhnn3SghoI1M/7/4PbfCwp5qruhxxaAGqbjgE0Z1EQEVUXRdEH0cddQ/qQHSNjsd53wd@9k3BTed8ksNM4mWsQ2NB@WcmNc96JKK1WRmK9AA) Link includes test cases. Explanation: The first stage deletes `!`s and the character they protect, the second stage deletes garbage, and the final stage counts the number of remaining groups.

Comment: Talk about the right tool for the job…

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 41 bytes

```javascript
x=>x.replace(/<(!?.)*?>|[^}]/g,'').length
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FchBDsIgEADAt3ACDNIPbLcPMTZB3KKGQFMaU4P7dsTjzMu9XfHbc93PKd@pLWM7RjzsRmt0ntQASkxWnyb8Xma@DsFIqW2kFPZH8zmVHMnGHNSiZK0gBJoK7uaRTYfAzgpVIP/jQwUAUkbuQJZatx8)

If it's acceptable to output in unary, remove the `.length` for 34 bytes.

This removes garbage and characters that aren't `}`, then counts what's left.

Comment: `/<(!?.)*?>|./g` saves you 6 bytes.

Comment: @Neil Nice, thanks!

Comment: @Neil What does `*?` do differently to `*`?

Comment: Unary output isn't normally allowed, is it?

Comment: @pxeger https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5343/can-numeric-input-output-be-in-unary

Comment: @emanresuA It's non-greedy, so it consumes as few repetitions as possible, i.e. stops after the first `>` (unless after an odd number of `!`s of course; the `!?` is still greedy).

Comment: @Neil Oh ok, thanks, I didn't realise that did that.

Comment: @emanresuA the most upvoted answer there says "only for sed/retina/etc.". JS's most natural number representation is definitely not unary.

Comment: @pxeger Edited :P, golfed off a byte anyway

Answer (score 4):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org), 35 bytes

```
tr -dc }<<<${1//<(!?|[^>])#>}|wc -c
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LYxLCsIwFEW3krQOKrQUwYGDx3MhpZYmfVahJJJE_KRZiZOCuKjuxogdnsM99_V-2tM0Z5acvjhGd0eqo67pBy3YuVfaUCMHbakRppVkP1d3LHZz6gwrOskCAKz8piwh4_uxOmC9TjGMN8kK-Z9OS7GtEu-Bc8w9tEJiyCNwjOjBcww_8SAb_5TGEAFDUi_xFw)

Removes all matches of the pattern `<(!?|[^>])#>`, which matches all garbage.

A few notes:

- Zsh doesn't support greedy vs. non-greedy matching, so I have to use `[^>]` rather than just `?`. (`?` matches any single character, but in order to get the garbage properly, `>`s must not be matched)
- I count closing braces rather than opening braces at the end - they give the same result since they're always balanced, but `}` does not need to be escaped thanks to the `ignore_closing_braces` option

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>39 36</s> 33 bytes

```ruby
->s{s.scan(/{(<(!?.)*?>)*/).size}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHLboMwELz3K5b0AhElaqv05DofUvVg3AUsWTbyGiWpxbdT8xBNSQ9eaXfGM@O168rrUL0PT5wCFSSFSQ8hZWlyKrL9iWf7Q1aQ@sZ@aKH62IV@9wmP8Ay1s11bPMzDEPp@Bl5ngFakz8MCCU32Hp8I@SQw0942DPbL4H/MIT03SjagPKGuQFrjhTIEtXClqDFbBQTPb85GY7mmTA2V7Ry0CiUS2OpOZxSKObZ11jtu38WSiXBbV/LLQoaUlJEYN6OBE@BFYuvBNwhakAdrIuQQ4p9I1Bq/cpAOhR@zjpgWrsZ/YiYJH91KGV1jk/DYxjXGEOPgisQYMzaGyRnfph9@AA)

Thanks lonelyelk for -3 bytes, I suck at regex.

Comment: You can save one character since you don't need to remove the closing «>»: [TIO](https://tio.run/##bZDdTsQgEIXvfYrperGtwW7U6BXig2zWhOKUkhBogEY3lWev9Cd17XrBJMz5OHMY11XnoX4d7pnvfSl9V@UHmmfl9/GdnYq7A9nvi1LYzgR4i3FooT7u@rg7wS08gHS2a8ubudn3Mc7C0yz4VYmkXySuvb3WJ4BMBjP2siHoL8H@DIf8s1GiARU86hqENYEr40FyV3GJxWrAGbk4G4/lmTISats5aBUK9GDrK5/RKOXY1tnvefsvmk3AZV3hxwWG3CsjMG1GA/OAXwLbAKFB0NwHsCZJDkHwBGmNHwSEQx7GrKOmuZP4T8wsY@O0SqSp6ZKxdE1rTCHGxhk9pdTYFIZQtk0//AA)

Comment: Or using a lazy regexp it can even be made shorter (with removing of the closing «>» though) [36 bytes](https://tio.run/##bZDdTsQgEIXvfYrperGtwW50o1dIH8R4QXFKSQg0QKObhmev9Cd17XrBJMz5OHMY19eXsXkbH5kffCl9X@cnmmdVWTxU7ESOx6IUtjcBqhjHDpr3wxAPH3APTyCd7bvybmkOQ4yLcF4EvymRDKvEtbe3@gyQ2WDBXncE/SXYn@GQf7VKtKCCR92AsCZwZTxI7mousdgMOCNXZ@exPlNGQmN7B51CgR5sc@MzGaUc@7r4vez/RbMZuK4b/LzCkHtlBKbNaGAe8FtgFyC0CJr7ANYkySEIniCt8ZOAcMjDlHXSNHcS/4mZZWyaVos0NV0ylq5pjSnE1Ligp5Qam8IQyvbpxx8)

Answer (score 4):

## TypeScript Types, 192 bytes

```
//@ts-ignore
type M<T,N=[],A=[0]>=T extends`${infer C}${infer T}`?M<C extends"!"?T extends`${string}${infer T}`?T:0:T,C extends"{"?[...N,...A]:N,C extends"<"?[]:C extends">"?[0]:A>:N["length"]
```

[Try It Online!](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTACBcGcFoEsHMB2B7ATgUwFDgJ4Ad0ACAWQB4AVAGgDkBeAbQF1KBBBgBkYD5bzD0AHuHSIAJpAAGAEgDesRADN0qQgGEAvrPlKV5dRID8ZVfyEjxAIgCEFg30HCxk2ZHCp58TXMXLCew+QAXOyBVCYO5pAWMrb0AHQJ1JQJcSyMgUnhZk4WpLHpWY6WXLGcgSxcGfQWADYi8OAAFhaMmNj4ROTshLQkeTLqFlyYIIRjAHoG7QR+AIw9fdEyA+qDw6MTU7gz5ABMC2RL6pQrQyPAY4ST050AzAf9y8cDJyurZxtXWx1+ACwP0VIL2BKy4a3Ol2u206AFYActSABDMEnJEomRo56Y8GfKE-cgANnhGKs6NIpKxFNRyPe6wumxufgA7MTyaTqQAjADGKLZpK4ryBFN5OHQkFIEpQYOOpDBH3pX0wQA)

### Ungolfed / Explanation

```
// Mode is [0] if parsing groups, or [] if parsing garbage
type Main<Str, Count=[], Mode=[0]> =
  // Get the first character of Str
  Str extends `${infer Char}${infer Rest}`
    ? Main<
      // If char is "!", set Str to Str[2..]; otherwise, set Str to Str[1..]
      Char extends "!" ? Rest extends`${string}${infer RestRest}` ? RestRest : 0 : Rest,
      // If char is "{", add Mode to Count
      Char extends "{" ? [...Count, ...Mode] : Count,
      // If char is "<", set Mode to [] (garbage); if char is ">", set Mode to [0] (not garbage)
      Char extends "<" ? [] : Char extends">" ? [0] : Mode
    >
    // Str is empty; return Count
    : Count["length"]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 78 bytes

```
s->a=b=0;#[1|d<-Vec(s),if(a,a=0,d=="!",!a=1,b,d==">"&&b=0,d=="<",!b=1,d=="{")]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY1NCsMgEEavolMICYyQrKseo5uQheanBEoqSTfBevZ0TG0bKOjwzXuj48w8iqvbBqa2RWijrCrPp7p6dlJc@jZfChyH3KBRJXZKAQfkRlVo905DltlkJBlLJmYPRbMZ525rvjChmZvH6UERYgNsoG8LZDX4AMjAex9CSgF9@EKMJ7o3kT@iEzEaDzc9jAn/6kfyHRzrUXIdgW1JUMM1tbSX5iJY@0VKOd1pHiVta4rtBQ)

When your language doesn't have regexp or any string pattern matching built-in...

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 39 bytes

```
≔⁰η≔¹ζ≔⁰εＦＳ«¿ε≔⁰ε≡ι!≔¹ε<≔⁰ζ>≔¹ζ}≧⁺ζη»Ｉη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9NCsIwEEbX7SkmrhKooFsbAuLKhSB6ghhiEyhtaaKiIWePU1uoXb553/wpI3vVyjqlvXO2auimAMPKfKJtAZ@Z0Gmke9sDPTbdw199b5uKMgYhz@wdqGawyIKunQb3sl4ZoPaXUxJLK7LawbxkGDsJPovNuH0SYtHxJyKKk@xGd7GV8fRcPxxmxl@ymMf8jJd6epDOU8NYmVIInBBRBC5vSsQCgQjEwAMRcSi8teOcN62ICCKm9bP@Ag) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔⁰η
```

Start off with no groups.

```
≔¹ζ
```

Start off with no garbage.

```
≔⁰ε
```

Start off without cancellation.

```
ＦＳ«
```

Loop over the input characters.

```
¿ε≔⁰ε
```

If the previous character was a `!` then cancel this character.

```
≡ι
```

Otherwise, switch on the current character.

```
!≔¹ε
```

If it's a `!` then cancel the next character.

```
<≔⁰ζ
```

If it's a `<` then turn on garbage.

```
>≔¹ζ
```

If it's a `>` then turn off garbage.

```
}≧⁺ζη
```

If it's a `}` that's not inside garbage then increment the number of groups.

```
»Ｉη
```

Output the final number of groups.

Answer (score 2):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 56 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

```
{⌈2÷˜≠','⊸≠⊸/{/˜¬∨⟜»×{+×1⌈|}`-˝"<>"=⌜}/˜¬∨⟜»'!'=}
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAge+KMiDLDt8uc4omgJywn4oq44omg4oq4L3vwnZWpL8ucwqziiKjin5zCu8OXe/Cdlagr8J2VqcOXMeKMiHzwnZWofWAty50iPD4iPeKMnPCdlal98J2VqS/LnMKs4oio4p+cwrsnISc98J2VqX0KCj4o4ouI4p+cRinCqOKfqCAie30iCiJ7e3t9fX0iCiJ7e30se319Igoie3t7fSx7fSx7e319fX0iCiJ7PHt9LHt9LHt7fX0+fSIKIns8YT4sPGE+LDxhPiw8YT59Igoie3s8YT59LHs8YT59LHs8YT59LHs8YT59fSIKInt7PCE+fSx7PCE+fSx7PCE+fSx7PGE+fX0iCiJ7ezwhIT4sezxhYmM+fSw8ISEhPj4se3s8eyE+fT59LDx5ZXM8PDxubz59fSw8Pn0i4p+pCg==)

-10 bytes from ovs.

Individually removes each main pattern (`!`, `<>`, `,`) and checks length. Then divide that by 2 and take ceiling.

Comment: `(=0)+|` can be shortened to `1⌈|`. And `('<'⊸=-'>'⊸=)` -> `-˝"<>"=⌜`.

Comment: This is actually 56 bytes. Javascript's `String.length` counts some characters such as `` and `` as 2 chars. You can fix that in the userscript by replacing `fun.length` with `Array.from(fun).length`.

Comment: oh, i see what's happening

Comment: @ovs update has been pushed

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 117 bytes

```python
n=0;g=1;s=input()
for x,y in zip(s,s[1:]):
 if '!'not in x+y:
  if y in'<>':g='<>'.index(y)
  if g:n+=y=='}'
print(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcpBDsIgEIXhfU8xxAVt2hiNuwpcxLioiEhiBgI0KRLOXiGuJt//xqX4tnjZD4DAQXu7utAdQFag2iLIBaX61KLbvPjHolWVqZJ2xaj8jvx01fx8DdygW2M/dC/rYZsSGISvcX2Ywu0834e5A/MCSija2LZtTDW11l4pE3TWvJ2jwafa@jT8Vz3jyBPntNDOeYOxx2Hfc2aEiCmz5SFFmSqIqMwsE1FaSCowxtCKUiHKDw)

A regex less solution, shorter than @Ajax1234

**[Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 114 bytes (Unsure if allowed)**

```python
n=0;g=1;s=input()
for x,y in zip(s,s[1:]):
 if '!'not in x+y:
  if y in'<>':g='<>'.index(y)
  if g*y=='}':print 1,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcpBbsMgEIXhvU8xJAvsFFV1lw5wkSoLhxKKFA0IsGSCOLsD6mr0/W98Tn8Ov48zIAgwwW0@DmdQDaj3BGpFpZ@tmD6v4b4a3WSblNsw6XCg@LoaMV@jsOi3NE7DwwXYWQaL8LJ@jCz@zMttWgawD6CEokt92z9yS731V8olXYzo59Pir97HPP2v5pKFoJUuPlhMMLPjOJXCCZGs8PWuZGUNRDYWXoisPWQdOefoZG2Q9fQG)

outputs in unary with space between each digit

Comment: Fails for `{<!!>,{}}` (should be 2 groups). Other than that, `n+=g*y=='}'` works for the first answer to make it the same length as the second.

Comment: `g=y=='>'` saves you another 7 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 74 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,m=1:s>''and(s[0]=='{'*m)+f(s[1+('!'==s[0]):],m^('><'[m]==s[0]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY3BCoMwEETvfkVy2lhzUHqTJD8iFrQqFZpE1IuEfLvdtaUVCrs7vJmBnbb14d113wf9bGzbNWyRVhflYgAa14mlymutIcDFptmAWGQCOGhNQVrW0t4EGAWVrT9eug9@Zs/R9Wx0zE@9E3laJoxN8@hWMQiKsBViEkKIkSTKEN8oachFVD80hI2Rp6U@ify7R8IPOt9vwg1Re0cXgRtE/IUlMrZ@UUo5j2WpTHwB)

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 68 bytes

```
Fold[StringDelete,#,{"!"~~_,"<"~~Shortest@__~~">"}]~StringCount~"{"&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY3PCoJAEMbvPsU6gqeJXmBbhKJz4FFEzLYU1AXdDrHsvrrNVqYRzL/v980wXalr2ZW6qcrpynbTUbWXLNVD098OspVaYoQGQnCuQODU0loNWo46KQrnQIDN3Xt9r@69dmAgnk6kdRaxjWDXLMpzFrNtEhgwFjBgYIyxdh4tGrtg9OHdD@ILEjMqBa5yvvUj/tWvG77Iuv64ofDkXJFDIhQk6TctevCQI@e8V3SAnB7a6Qk)

Answer (score 2):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), <strike>170</strike> 166 bytes

```rust
|i:&str|{let(mut g,mut s)=(0,vec![123]);for c in i.bytes(){match&[s[s.len()-1],c]{b"<!"|b"{<"|b"{{"=>s.push(c),[33,_]|b"<>"=>{s.pop();}b"{}"=>{g+=1;s.pop();}_=>()}}g}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLRboIwFIbveYqWC9JmVYdku5DSPQghBkhREq2Mli2m9tnZKTOOqU045Hz//5@eEPpBm7FR6Fi2ilBkAwTnIA1qUIbGS7uJtOkvFgg5DgbtmK@aZuSVfcka5/E6KWjanHpUo1ahdlmdjdSE2mNp6n2U61wvDxJGL@KC1YWtQo7DSxVaPlUbZkIvu0HvSU1ZniRsWwDnArgF4dQRmjowOg92L1mc3ug2E4Q6t3Oj3zkNptX9JqRV3WAYKpX@lj31e0X5pPpD/DCGYsrmyFrnPE7usGP2KZ8ENqW8/P5f5n@yeHIZLwWbPc/W8Zg9VO98u3fiSZ3Xq3P94MTCq1UNLmiwgBZ2hZAHZ6k55@oEYcbF/Kri@l/40/WtMgeFYeDmw6GFQP4N5v8fPb0FVitUai17g2/ot9/KT0yihkRTkt5FXeCC8Qc)

- -4 bytes by not using `Option` (thanks @AnttiP)

Comment: -4 bytes by removing the question mark: `|i:&str|{let(mut g,mut s)=(0,vec![123]);for c in i.bytes(){match&[s[s.len()-1],c]{b"<!"|b"{<"|b"{{"=>s.push(c),[33,_]|b"<>"=>{s.pop();}b"{}"=>{g+=1;s.pop();}_=>()}}g}`

Answer (score 2):

## x86 32-bit machine code, 31 bytes

```
56 96 31 d2 31 c9 4a 42 41 ac 3c 21 75 01 46 3c 3e 74 f1 e2 f3 7a f1 73 ee 48 7b ed 5e 92 c3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVJRb5wwDH7Pr/AxTYJTWvWuaqVxlKd2r/sB63QKIYVUIaCEa29C/PUxO1cBVRE4@T5/No4deVVJOU3ftJXmVCrIfF/q9rrO2SfK6II4djyKvne6OPXqeIxjp6pOuCbeJUkC2vZQ@d7FshZuCz45MOEbiFn0bK8r0xbCBH9EBG3SsAN8upOvQXk9E2dZV0RwUOK8sK0DVZ45mUDKXXohJZFyUZZKziL9mGJtC3YpXPCH3iA2bemLOVo2HQjD4ea8383kq1XgZxQSfBTs03XI7dMSokAuCUzbduAWZ6fWCPPpx8/1r07@2rVglnZhoq/dCo1ZxTjVRwyHQHNphLYxbYSrJAeaEGy3CN4SNrBwZqL87/3djz@HQLzX2iiIvRT2JY6@7@/ufcRxqrB5gKdfP5MgCtU4TEwS/WxREa6AT5JLFizi5CzcHNjIpmkY2TAM40jLyIfxAjm9xCLMFpgTFDlffaSnhX@xwbMJaG1nzyYnVEhkEWxyhPgvFBHxV/ksy2yLYp7l4z/5YkTlp6vmdo8GL/EDnlCZ/w)

Following the `regparm(1)` calling convention, this takes the address of a null-terminated byte string in EAX.

Assembly:

```
.text                   # In the main loop, EDX will count the number of {
.global gstr            #  and ECX will be 1 outside garbage, 0 inside garbage.
.intel_syntax noprefix
gstr:
    push esi        # Save the value of ESI onto the stack
    xchg esi, eax   # Switch the string address into ESI
    xor edx, edx    # Set EDX to 0
c1: xor ecx, ecx    # Set ECX to 0
    dec edx         #  (These two instructions have a net effect of nothing,
iD: inc edx         #    but we can jump into the middle to add 1 to EDX.)
r:  inc ecx         # Increment ECX, at first to 1
l:  lodsb           # Read a character from the string into AL
    cmp al, 0x21    # Check for !
    jne s           #  Jump if not !
    inc esi         #  If !, increment ESI to skip the next character
s:  cmp al, 0x3E    # Compare with >
    je c1           #  Jump on > to reset ECX to 1
    loop r          # Decrement ECX and jump (to restore it and proceed)
                    #  if it was 0 (within garbage)
    jpe r           # Jump (same) to ignore } and ,
    jnc iD          # Jump on { to count up in EDX (and restore ECX) 
    dec eax         # Decrement EAX, setting PF from the low 8 bits
    jpo l           # Jump on < to proceed (ECX remains 0)
    pop esi         # NUL: Restore the value of ESI from the stack
    xchg edx, eax   # Switch the count into EAX
    ret             # Return
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>17</s> 16 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
'!š¬ìKDŒ€…<ÿ>K¤¢
```

Despite 05AB1E's lack of regex, it turned out surprisingly short. :)

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fXfHowkNrDq/xdjk66VHTmkcNy2wO77fzPrTk0KL//6urbRQV7XSqbRKTku1qdYAcRTsgt9qmWtGuFiRQmVpsY2OTl29XC@TY1QIA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXLf3XFowsPrTm8xtvl6KRHTWseNSyzObzfzvvQkkOL/uv8j1aqrlXSUaqurq6thTBqdaprYUI6IASSAQvYIATsIAKJdjpIGKILxNDBIKFyimA@Mokkp2gH4iclA8WBHEU7IBdoJ1AZSKAytdjGxiYvH6hcxwZmlR1IIciAWAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
         # Remove all "!" and the character after it:
'!š     '#  Split the (implicit) input-string to a list of characters, and prepend a "!"
   ¬     #  Push the first item (without popping), which is the "!"
    ì    #  Prepend this "!" in front of each character
     K   #  Remove all those 2-char strings from the (implicit) input-string
         #  (the `š¬` is necessary to first remove all "!!")
         # Remove all "<...>" garbage groups:
D        #  Duplicate the string
 Œ       #  Pop the copy, and push all its substrings
  €      #  Map each substring to:
   …<ÿ>  #  Prepend a "<" and append a ">"
       K #  Remove all those from the string as well
         # Count how many groups are left:
¤        #  Push the last character (without popping), which is "}"
 ¢       #  Count how many "}" are in the string
         # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python3, 156 bytes:

```
f=lambda x,g=0,c=0,i=0:c if not x else f(x[1:],(g:=(x[0]=='<'or(x[0]!='>'and g))),c+(not g and x[0]=='}' and not i),x[0]=='!'or(i and x[0]not in [",","}"]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU7NjoIwEL7vU0y9tM3OAePFkLYvYjggAjZxC0EOGNJnZ2caowZMO5P5/ibTP8ZrFw7HfliWxt7Kv/OlhAlbm2FF5W2WV@AbCN0IE9S3ew2Nmk77vEDV5pbGrLBWGtkNaRZWOlmGC7Raa6x@FQdbYOZpjTIh5r3GJyk471@2JAY47ZBe3BVaL/3gw6gaJecotf55w3mOcU1FnOPWhvzZvZLMW3JrqXT4UeudTOGmb1wiKZ/9q0s4Vs4VOQgIR5BuowATj/pujAkdBdGkQ5Z/)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 54 bytes

```python
lambda x:re.sub('<(!?.)*?>','',x).count('{')
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcixCsMgEADQvV8Rp/OKuHQr18uPZNHU0ECjYgwkiN9u7fhevPIn@EdbXlP7ms2@zXA@k9P7YSWQFKPG@8igANSJeg6HzxIK4G3dYkh5SK7FtPZcehcSglUhY2euqkNwZ6EiuP7jcjsR@cC1gysgth8)

Port of my JS answer. Go read that, it's almost the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 26 bytes

```perl
s/!.//g;s/<.*?>//g;$_=y;{;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY1NCsJADIX33mLAlUxn6qKriekJPIOoFBFKZ3DclJCrG5MKWhDy9733IGV4jJ1IjS7EeEs1Qtj1aOf2dJgTJRHiDREx22JP/EFvZaoi/BANz@hXbXlb/m8ujltoPb@OQ6PLVVUFh4r6S0MmzEMFgClr2APyK5fnPU9VmjJKc@xCu2/f)

Answer (score 1):

## SM83, 24 bytes

Input in `hl` as null-terminated string.
Output in `bc`.

```
2A B7 C8 FE 7B 20 01 03
FE 3C 20 F4 2A FE 3E 28
EF FE 21 20 F7 23 18 F4
```

```
f:
    ld a,(hl+)      ;; 2A       ;; load char
    or a            ;; B7       ;; test for 0
    ret z           ;; C8       ;; if so, at end; return
    cp '{'          ;; FE 7B
    jr nz,x         ;; 20 01    ;; if not '{'
    inc bc          ;; 03       ;; increment result
x:
    cp '<'          ;; FE 3C    ;; if not '<'
    jr nz,f         ;; 20 F4    ;; loop
l:                              ;; degarbaging:
    ld a,(hl+)      ;; 2A       ;; load char
    cp '>'          ;; FE 3E    ;; if '>'
    jr z,f          ;; 28 EF    ;; go back to start
    cp '!'          ;; FE 21    ;; if not '!'
    jr nz,l         ;; 20 F7    ;; continue degarbaging
    inc hl          ;; 23       ;; skip char
    jr l            ;; 18 F4    ;; and continue degarbaging
```